# Autofilter to return only data between two numbers, but returns blanks instead

Tags: excel, vba, long-integer, autofilter

Having trouble getting an autofilter to return only data between two numbers, defined as variable as follows:

My variables are Long and defined as an upper limit and a lower limit, in this case 7 and -500 respectively...

```
Dim dateRangeUpr As Long
Dim dateRangeLwr As Long
```

Code continues to the definition of the variable...

```
If ReleaseDatesReportBtnClick = True And reports.ComboBox13.Value = "This Week Only" Then
        dateRangeUpr = 7
        dateRangeLwr = -500
```

The below line of Code ***should*** return an autofilter that only shows data between 7 & -500, however it is retuning only blanks...

```
If filterColumn = 8 And ComboBox13.Value = "This Week Only" Or "Late Tasks Only" Then
        Range("A1:I10000").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=dateRangeUpr, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=dateRangeLwr
```

Answer (score 0):

Your current AutoFilter code is telling VBA to return data **equal to** both your upper and lower limits, which is why it returns blanks.

To return data **between** your upper and lower limits you need to adjust your AutoFilter code as follows (note the >= and <= additions to your criteria).

```
Range("A1:I10000").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<=" & dateRangeUpr, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:=">=" & dateRangeLwr
```

Comment: Thanks @TSK but it is still only returning blanks.